# Necessary Routing for Invoking Lambda from ECS Across Different VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpc

I have two VPCs within a single AWS account. One VPC is running ECS services, and the other is running Lambda functions. I want to invoke these Lambda functions from the ECS services. Below are the prerequisites:

A. Both ECS and Lambda are in a Private Subnet, and neither has internet routing.
B. The ECS Task Role has been granted sufficient permissions to execute Lambda functions.

I'm considering the following approaches:

1. Create a VPC Endpoint for Lambda in the VPC where ECS is running. ECS can invoke the Lambda function via this VPC Endpoint.
2. Since both are in different VPCs and don't have internet routing, I would need to connect the two VPCs. I could use:

- VPC Peering
- PrivateLink (i.e., ECS -> VPC Endpoint (interface) --PrivateLink-- VPC Endpoint Service -> NLB -> ALB -> Lambda function)

Which approach is the correct one to take given the prerequisites?

Answer (score 0):

The first option is correct and I would say is the best option. You only need the lambda VPC interface endpoint created in the VPC where ECS is running.